# Do we require a transit visa to connect through Abu Dhabi, UAE?

Tags: transit-visas, uae

We are about to visit the United States. Our travel itinerary on Etihad Airways is as follows:

Departure flight
Colombo - Abu Dhabi 8.25 hr layover - Los Angeles

Return flight
Chicago  - Abu Dhabi 15 hr layover - Colombo

Do we need transit visas for connections in the UAE?

Do we have to re-check our baggage in Abu Dhabi, as well? If we do, would we require a visa

Comment: Pls really need to know your nationality. And which airlines you're flying with. And whether it's all on one booking.

Comment: Hi .. Sri Lankan

Comment: Ethid  Airways and yes it's all one booking.. thanks

Comment: No then you don’t need a transit visa if you stay airside. If you want to go explore the city then yes you do. And you will not have to collect and recheck your bags in any case.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. was really unsure of the visa requirement..

Comment: @Giorgio I've acted upon your advice :)

Answer (score 1):

**You do not require a transit visa** as long as you plan to stay airside.

However getting a visa for a quick tour of the city will not be a big hassle and you can even apply for one on Etihad's website. (Passengers flying Emirates can apply on theirs)

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
> Visa is required for transit between Dubai International Airport (DXB) and Dubai Al Maktoum International (DWC).

Source: [Timatic Via Emirates Visa Check](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=LK&NV=Sri%20Lanka&DC=US&DV=United%20States&TC=AE&TV=United%20Arab%20Emirates&h=ff4cc0a8444b1dfe543143338d32ac6b79d7ccbd)

> Do we have to re-check our baggage in Abu Dhabi, as well? If we do, would we require a visa

No, if it is a single booking you do not have to collect and re-check your baggage.

**Bonus**

You will go through the US Immigration processes at AUH because Abu Dhabi is a preclearance port, that means that when you reach the US you will not have to go through any more immigration procedures.